# How to declare that the composition of two types is a monad

Tags: haskell

I have function:

```hs
step :: forall m . (MonadState IntCodeState m) => m (Maybe ())
```

When I use `do` notation in the body of the function, it uses `m` as the monad. As you might expect, I actually want it to be using `m Maybe`. But, it doesn't understand that `m Maybe` is a monad. How do I express that to Haskell?

EDIT: This may be slightly malformed at the moment. The concrete type should be
`StateT IntCodeState Maybe ()`, but I'm trying not to declare the concrete type, so the question is: how do I declare that?

EDIT 2: Another attempt: I've got some functions that look like this:

```
getValueIndex :: (MonadState IntCodeState m) => Int -> m (Maybe Int)
```

Here, I'm working on the level of the state monad. However, I now want to be able to act "as if" `m Maybe` was the monad. I was hoping this was simple but I can't figure out a way of expressing it. The code I want to write looks like this

```
step :: forall m . (MonadState IntCodeState m) => m (Maybe ())
step = do
    full <- opCode
    let len = length (snd full) + 1
    process full <* (next += len)
```

But opCode returns a `m (Maybe a)` and I want `full` to be an `a`

Comment: Can you please add the function body you're getting errors with as well?

Comment: Sounds like you should be explicitly using `MaybeT m`.

Comment: Also note: if `m` accepts one type argument (`m :: * -> *`), then `m Maybe` is invalid, did you mean `m (Maybe ())` or a composition of `m` and `MaybeT`?

Comment: Still looks like `MaybeT` - what do you want to do inside the function? What are the error messages, if any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But opCode returns a `m (Maybe a)` and I want `full` to be an `a`

Looks like you want to use the [`MaybeT` *monad transformer*](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.18/transformers-0.5.6.2/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html#v:runMaybeT), which is `m (Maybe a)` under the hood, with its `Monad` instance doing what you need:

> The MaybeT monad transformer extends a monad with the ability to exit the computation without returning a value.
>
> A sequence of actions produces a value only if all the actions in the sequence do. If one exits, the rest of the sequence is skipped and the composite action exits.

Here are the types:

```
MaybeT :: m (Maybe a) -> MaybeT m a

runMaybeT :: MaybeT m a -> m (Maybe a)
```

This will also be helpful, specialised from `MonadTrans`:

```
lift :: m a -> MaybeT m a
```

So in your case:

```
step :: forall m . (MonadState IntCodeState m) => m (Maybe ())
step = runMaybeT $ do
    full <- MaybeT opCode -- :: MaybeT opCode :: MaybeT m a, full :: a
    let len = length (snd full) + 1
    lift $ process full <* (next += len)
```

I've assumed `process` returns an `m ()` and used `lift` to change it into `MaybeT m ()`.

Comment: Thankyou, it really wasn't obvious to me how MaybeT would help, but this makes it clear.